# how to remove leading zeroes from a string

Tags: vbscript

I have to extract the integer value from a string.
Its actually an amount field.

Say string can be `000000000000512` or `0000040000000`
I want only the integer value from this string i.e.; 512/ 40000000
Please help with this in VB scripting

Answer (score 11):

```
CInt("000000000000512")
```

See conversion functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

Use Clng if you expect to have large numbers, as already pointed out in a comment:

```
Clng("000000004000512")
```

otherwise you'll have an overflow, as variant's subtype int is 16 bit in vbscript

Comment: Your code `CInt('000000000000512')` has syntax error ... you cannot use `'` (single quote) for the string literal in VBscript. `'` (single quote) is used for comment

Comment: And `CInt("0000040000000")` will cause **Overflow** error ... So, will `CLng()` be better choice?

Comment: If neither of these work, I've always been partial to vVarname = vVarname + 0, it will pick the correct precision for you. Also, the biggest conversion function I think is CDbl().

Comment: When I try this with a variable thats holding a value of "00002219"

CInt(strNumVar)

Comment: This did not work for me, if the number was too long, this would give a number with exponent. for example   1.2E+10. See my answer below for an alternative

Answer (score 7):

This will work even with a crazy long number

```
Function RemoveLeadingZeroes(ByVal str)
Dim tempStr
tempStr = str
While Left(tempStr,1) = "0" AND tempStr <> ""
    tempStr = Right(tempStr,Len(tempStr)-1)
Wend
RemoveLeadingZeroes = tempStr
End Function

strNewFileName = RemoveLeadingZeroes("0009283479283749823749872392384")
```

Answer (score 4):

I've used this technique before:

- replace the zeros with spaces
- left trim
- replace the spaces with zeros

`Replace(LTrim(Replace(str, "0", " ")), " ", "0")`

Note, this doesn't work if str has meaningful spaces in it.

Comment: I like this because it works in any base (binary, hex, etc.).  The only problem is that you end up with "" if your string was only zeros.  That's easy to fix with an if statement though

Answer (score 3):

Use the Absolute Value of the number.

http://ss64.com/vb/abs.html

```
Var = ABS(Var)
```

Comment: This may work when the number is expected to be only positive. Will give the wrong answer when trimming leading 0's from a negative number.

Comment: I would add a check for negative first and then subtract the answer from zero if true.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex:

```
Regex.Replace("000000000000512", "^0+", "") ' returns "512"
Regex.Replace("0000040000000", "^0+", "") ' returns "40000000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Function TrimLeadingZeros(value)
    TrimLeadingZeros = value    
    while left(TrimLeadingZeros, 1) = "0" and TrimLeadingZeros <> "0"
        TrimLeadingZeros = mid(TrimLeadingZeros, 2)
    wend
End Function
```

or

```
Function TrimLeadingZeros(value)
    dim i
    i = 1
    while i < len(value) and mid(value,i,1) = "0"
        i = i + 1
    wend
    
    TrimLeadingZeros = mid(value, i)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your string includes digits and characters, use a Do While statement:

```
string = "00000456ABC"

Do While Left(string, 1) = "0"
     string = Right(string, (Len(string)-1))
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this solution seems do not work:

```
string = "00000456ABC"
Do While Left(string, 1) = "0"
string = Right(string, (Len(string)-1))
Loop
```

This, work:

```
    Do
string = Strings.Right(string, (Len(string) - 1))
Loop Until Strings.Left(string, 1) <> "0"
TextBox11.Text = string
```

Answer (score 0):

format(myString,"0") will do the job

Example A:
debug.? format("00000000000000000","0")
0

Example B:
debug.? format("00000001234567890","0")
1234567890

Answer (score -1):

```
Function TrimLZ(str)  
   If Left(str, 1) = "0" Then
      TrimLZ = TrimLZ(Mid(str, 2, Len(str)))
   Else
      TrimLZ = str
   End If
End Function
```