# Delete leading zeros in alphanumeric strings

Tags: vba, ms-access

I use *Access 2016*. I want to use VBA to delete the zeroes (*0*) that are to the right of letters  and to the left of numbers.

I have a table with alphanumeric fields such as this:

```
A00123050   AB00245098 TH00001250
```

I would like to delete the leading zeroes (after the leading letters) in each field like this:

```
A123050  AB245098 TH1250
```

Comment: Hi! Please note that Stack Overflow is an English-only site. Edit your question into English or it will likely be closed as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: Just wrote a translation, it is in edit review.

Comment: @StephaneMartin I appreciate your intentions, but read [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/7296893) : _Please do not translate posts for the OP. They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate the post we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided (by comments, answers, or Help Center content)._

Comment: Note that, while your edited question is no longer that unclear, you're not sharing an attempt, and it's possibly too broad (and half-answered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35637357/7296893), it currently deletes all leading zeroes, but you can easily adapt it to only remove the first and last zero)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth et al: The question is clear, and here is a fancy solution: `StrippedCode = Left(Code, Len(Code) - (Len(StrReverse(Val("1" & StrReverse(Code)))) - 1)) & CStr(Val(StrReverse(Val("1" & StrReverse(Code)))) \ 10)`

Comment: @Gustav see the edits, it wasn't when it was posted, or when it was closed. Now it probably is a duplicate, that's why I haven't voted to reopen

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Yes, I saw your note but, as you stated, it is only the (easy) half of a solution, and the part left is really what this question is about.

Comment: @Gustav It would be what the question was about if OP had shared this in his attempt. Currently, it's either too broad (since OP wants to do two things at once and doesn't show an attempt nor specifies what is hard) or a duplicate in my opinion, or still unclear, since I see the expected output doesnt fit the question

Comment: Hi all.I inspire the solution of Erik that I put in a function. It works very well. Solved problem. Thank for all .

Comment: @SAIDBACHIRI could you please post your solution as an answer? This way others who have the same problem can see how you solved it.

Comment: Hi all. anything special.  in a standar module: Public Function DeleteZero (ByVal Code as String) on ​​error goto Err_DeleteZero     DeleteZero = Left (Code, Len (Code) - (Len (StrReverse (Val ("1" & StrReverse (Code))) ) - 1)) & CStr (Val (StrReverse (Val ("1" & StrReverse (Code)))) \ 10) Err_DeleteZero: ...Then I created an updated query. Where I put DeleteZero ([Code]). Then I copied the sql code of the query to execute it on click of a botton  with DoSetWarning. For me it works very well. Probably for the other he wants a Null's management. Thank you . sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Based on the edited question, it's just this simple. Btw, this assumes there is at least 1 leading alpha character.

```
Function TrimLeadingZeros(MyString As String) As String
   Dim Idx As Integer
   For Idx = 2 To Len(MyString)
      If IsNumeric(Mid(MyString, Idx, 1)) Then
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
   TrimLeadingZeros = Left(MyString, Idx - 1) & CStr(CLng(Mid(MyString, Idx)))
End Function
```